redis-om python custom primary key
I've been trying to create a custom PK based on fields in the model.
https://redis.io/learn/develop/python/redis-om
"The default ID generation function creates ULIDs, though you can change the function that generates the primary key for models if you'd like to use a different kind of primary key."
I would like to customise the generation of primary keys based on some of the fields of the model (instance).
I noticed that if I create a field called "pk," redis-om does take this value as the primary key.
But is there a way. I can just declaratively assign fields as primary keys?

You can add Field(primary_key=True) to any of the attributes in your model.
Here is the code provided in their example with the default pk:
import datetime
from typing import Optional

from redis_om import HashModel


class Customer(HashModel):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    join_date: datetime.date
    age: int
    bio: Optional[str] = "Super dope"


andrew = Customer(
    first_name="Andrew",
    last_name="Brookins",
    email="andrew.brookins@example.com",
    join_date=datetime.date.today(),
    age=38)

print(andrew.pk)
# > '01FJM6PH661HCNNRC884H6K30C'

andrew.save()
assert Customer.get(andrew.custom_pk) == andrew

To assign your own primary key, you would update the code as follows:
import datetime
from typing import Optional

from redis_om import HashModel, Field


class Customer(HashModel):
    custom_pk:str = Field(primary_key=True)
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    email: str
    join_date: datetime.date
    age: int
    bio: Optional[str] = "Super dope"


andrew = Customer(
    custom_pk = "customPkValue",
    first_name="Andrew",
    last_name="Brookins",
    email="andrew.brookins@example.com",
    join_date=datetime.date.today(),
    age=38)
    
andrew.save()

assert Customer.get(andrew.custom_pk) == andrew


have you tried running your code and it works for you ?

No, this works with JsonModel though

It doesn’t work with redis json. That was the question.
